# How to open another xaml page when listview is selected(Xamarin Forms)?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a set of values and fields which is displayed in a list view.
Can somebody help me to achieve this.

How to open a new xaml page when listview is selected and display the selected listview alone in the new xaml page?

Comment: There are dozens of examples of simple page navigation available on the Xamarin site.  Have you looked at any of them?

Comment: Read about MasterDetailPage

Comment: I am able to navigate but don't know to bring the selected listview to that page